# Convert contour to 2d point list in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

The following is a contour structure returned by OpenCV. It's deeply nested, the first element of the tuple is a list of points in the contour.

Any idea to convert this to a 2d point list (n x 2)? I think `numpy.reshape` can be used, but I couldn't find a very general way to do that. Thanks.

```
contours = cv2.findContours(bw_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours =>
   ([array([[[ 19,  20]],

   [[ 18,  21]],

   [[ 17,  21]],

   [[ 17,  22]],

   [[ 16,  23]],

   [[ 16, 130]],

   [[ 17, 131]],

   [[ 17, 132]],

   [[ 21, 132]],

   [[ 43, 110]],

   [[ 44, 110]],

   [[ 75, 141]],

   [[ 81, 141]],

   [[109, 113]],

   [[145, 149]],

   [[149, 149]],

   [[149,  21]],

   [[148,  21]],

   [[147,  20]]], dtype=int32)], array([[[-1, -1, -1, -1]]], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: just be a bit caucious here. contours are *ordered* lists of points. if you go and just join them all into a single list, you destroy that order (you can no more use moments or similar on it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = np.vstack(contours).squeeze()
```

Note that cv2.findContours actually return 2 items. "contours" here is a list. So we use numpy's `vstack()` to stack them together, followed by `squeeze()` to remove any redundant axis.

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful. For me was necessary an extra step `contours= [ np.array(contours) ]` after squeeze.